# What should I build my new nomenclature package on top of?

Tags: bibliographies, glossaries, auxiliary-files, nomenclature

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`concepts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/concepts)

*This is a major edit. In my previous attempt I overgeneralized, which obfuscated my real question.*

---

I'd like to write a new package which I want to use for my PhD thesis: a nomenclature management package. Why a new one? I've been looking into it, and a package with the features I need doesn't seem to exist yet. In particular, `nomencl` is too limited for my purpose. I'd like to be able to:

- associate a certain formal concept with:

  - a name + plural form (e.g. `delta` + `deltas`)
  - a description (e.g. `a module which can transform one product into another`)
  - a list of variable names, used to represent instances of it (e.g. `x, y, z`)
  - a macro prefix, used to typeset those variables/constants in the document (e.g. `\d`)
- arbitrarily assign available variable names to occurrences of `\d1`, `\d2`, etc.
- report an error if there are more macros used than names available
- report an error if any variable name is associated with more than one concept

  - (within two connected scopes: see my [other package idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77897/storing-unexpanded-macro-definitions-including-1-2-for-later-use-now/78029#78029))
- generate a table/list with all relevant info, sorted by occurrence in the document
- generate sentence fragments such as `for all deltas $x, y$ and products $p$` from macros such as `\forallvars{\d1,\d2,\p1}`

Maybe some other stuff I didn't think of yet.

**My question is:** what should I start off with if I want to create this package with a minimum of hassle?

The text below contains some research on the many possible options I could consider.

---

An index, a glossary, a nomenclature and a bibliography all feel like the same thing to me, from a technical point of view. Data is gathered from the entire document, written to a file (possibly), formatted/transformed in some way, then made available for output in various forms. So possibly any package that does this sort of thing could serve as a starting-point for me.

Many different techniques already exist:

- [bibtex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtex), [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), [biber](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber) (aimed at bibliographies)
- [makeindex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeindex), [xindy](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xindy) (aimed at glossaries)
- [newfile](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/newfile) ('manually')
- pure (La)TeX, no intermediate file

Quite some existing packages manage [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/characterization/primary/document-parts/glossary/) or [nomenclatures](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=nomenclature&search_type=description). They are usually built on top of bibtex or makeindex/xindy, but not always. And then there are also [tons](http://www.ctan.org/characterization/primary/document-parts/index/) and [tons](http://www.ctan.org/characterization/primary/document-parts/bibliography/others/) [of](http://www.ctan.org/characterization/primary/document-parts/bibliography/bibliographic-styles/) [packages](http://www.ctan.org/characterization/primary/document-parts/bibliography/) built around those that tweak little options or add new features.

So... there are just too many options to consider. I can't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: This is waaaay to wide of a question imho. A bibliography most definitely is something entirely different than the others. So one question might be about the difference between the other three. As for preferable packages, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/ should cover the bibliography part, and I think we already have questions about the other concepts as well, but I don't follow those since I don't use them. You'll find them by searching. So I would strongly encourage you to narrow this question down a lot (and ask more separate questions if necessary).

Comment: Hm. My question is basically: "What would be the best package/system to build my own nomenclature package on top of?" The extra information was just to show that I did some research before asking. Asking for a general comparison was meant to help make the answer useful to more people. +++++ Thanks for the link! It's generally informative, but not for my specific use-case.

Comment: I does look like you did some thorough research first, thanks for that! `:)` As for your question, I'd recommend then actually putting more of an emphasis on the fact that you want to put a package _on top of_ one of these packages -- which is vastly different from what most users would be looking for in such a package, I suppose. So yeah, I'd say minimize the "general" part and put it at the end (because that'd be kind of duplicate-y) and focus your question on the fact that you want to develop a package. Technically, that might be _too localized_, but we generally like&support new packages.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice! I have now rewritten my question. I hope this is more appropriate. +++++ Incidentally, I now suspect the package `glossaries` is the best starting point for me. It seems extremely flexible and well-maintained. I'm working on that now, but I'd still like to hear more opinions. If I eventually succeed by myself, I'll post my own answer.

Comment: Have you read [Nicola Talbot's article about creating a glossary](http://www.latex-community.org/component/content/article/55-latex-general/456-glossary-without-makeindex) without the help of makeindex/xindy?

Comment: @cgnieder: Excellent! :-) I've looked through it a bit, and it seems extremely relevant. Quite a bit of coincidence that the author of the package I'm considering wrote an article on how to write the package I need, using a package I'm already quite familiar with (`datatool`), mere weeks before I start writing. :-) I'm definitely reading the article. But I might still go for `glossaries` itself, since I can then leverage its many options. (I don't particularly mind having to do multiple runs. Eclipse does it for me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first useful version of this package is now on CTAN, called `concepts`. It was written 'from scratch', without another package as the base.

However, I've decided to build the next version on top of `glossaries`, as it already implements much of the functionality, has many useful features and is actively maintained and well documented.