# Automatically clean (numerous) customization macros gathered in an auxiliary file

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files, grouping

I have to gather, in a single source file, source files from several authors,
each of them with its own (many) `\newcommand`, `\newtheorem`, etc. I'd like to limit the scope of each of these customizations, in the spirit of [Limit macro/newcommand scope to section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105684/18401). The egreg's nice solution with `\onlysectioncommands{...,...,...}` has in my case the drawback that these `\newcommand`, `\newtheorem`, etc. may each time be numerous.

Hence, if each customization set is put in an auxiliary file, say
`⟨author⟩-customization.tex`, I'm looking for a clever `\cleancustomization`
macro that lets me able to do something like:

```
...
%
\input{author1-customization}
\input{author1-source}
\cleancustomization{author1-customization}
%
\input{author2-customization}
\input{author2-source}
\cleancustomization{author2-customization}
%
\input{author3-customization}
\input{author3-source}
\cleancustomization{author3-customization}
%
...
```

In other words, `\cleancustomization` should be given a fixed list of
customization macros (`\newcommand`, `\newtheorem`, etc.), and then be able to parse the file given in argument and automatically `\undef`ine all the commands, theorems, etc. defined inside this file.

Do you see a (`LaTeX3`) way for doing this?

Comment: You could patch `\newcommand`, `\newtheorem` etc... so that they add the macros names in a list similar to egreg's `\sectioncommandslist`, then `\cleancustomization` would process it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\saved@ifdefinable}{}
\newcommand*{\saved@rc@ifdefinable}{}
\newcommand{\startcustomization}{
    \def\@renewedcommands{}
    \def\@newedcommands{}
    \let\saved@ifdefinable\@ifdefinable
    \let\saved@rc@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
    \newcommand{\@saveforrestore}[1]{%
        \ifinlist{##1}{\@renewedcommands}{}{%
            \listadd\@renewedcommands##1%
            \expandafter\let\csname saved@\string##1\endcsname##1%
    }}
    \renewcommand{\@ifdefinable}[2]{%
        \listadd\@newedcommands##1%
        \saved@ifdefinable{##1}{##2}%
    }
    \let\@@ifdefinable\@ifdefinable
    \renewcommand{\@rc@ifdefinable}[2]{%
        \@saveforrestore##1%
        \saved@rc@ifdefinable{##1}{##2}%
    }
}
\newcommand{\cleancustomization}{%
    \newcommand{\saved@restore}[1]{\expandafter\let\expandafter##1\csname saved@\string##1\endcsname}%
    \forlistloop{\saved@restore}{\@renewedcommands}%
    \forlistloop{\undef}{\@newedcommands}%

    \let\@ifdefinable\saved@ifdefinable%
    \let\@rc@ifdefinable\saved@@ifdefinable%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\startcustomization
    \newcommand*{\blipo}{Jill}
    \renewcommand\emph[1]{\textbf{#1}}
    Hello \blipo{}. \blipo{} is \emph{blonde}
\cleancustomization

Not defined here. \emph{Attempt} to use it--- ``generates'' error.
\end{document}
```

I defined two commands `\startcustomization` and `\cleancustomization` so that every command defined between the two will be undefined after `\cleancustomization`.
I patched `\@ifdefinable`, as mentionned in [this TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73279/29394).

EDIT: Patching `\@rc@ifdefinable`, you can save the original macros when `\renewcommand` is used (in this code I save it in `\saved@\macro`, after checking that the macro isn't saved yet). This way, it is possible to restore the commands when `\cleancustomization` is used.

Comment: In order to insure this clever answer works in case of personal `\renewcommand`s, it is sufficient (necessary?) to patch `\@@ifdefinable` exactly in the same way `\@ifdefinable` is.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé See my updated answer. The code is not so clean, but I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

May be too late but i find that we can do this with just grouping

```
\begingroup
\input{author1-customization}
\input{author1-source}
\endgroup
%
\begingroup
\input{author2-customization}
\input{author2-source}
\endgroup
%
\begingroup
\input{author3-customization}
\input{author3-source}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Surprisingly (at least for me), grouping is OK for `\newcommand`: `\newcommand{\foo}{bar}` in a first group doesn't conflict with `\newcommand{\foo}{baz}` in a subsequent group. But, unfortunately, this doesn't work for instance for `\newtheorem`: `\newtheorem{theo}{Bar}` in a first group conflicts with `\newtheorem{theo}{Baz}` in a subsequent group. And this is strange: though `\foo` was already defined and could be defined again, here the error message tells: `! LaTeX Error: Command \theo already defined.`

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Ok. \newtheorem use internally \global\@namedef{#1} and \global\@namedef{end#1} soo grouping does not work