# Isolate Latex Environments

Tags: listings, verbatim, preview

I want to build a framework for sharing latex mathematics exercises. When trying to assemble exercises from different authors into one "homework assignment", I have a problem. How can I deal with their different macros and settings? Is there some way to do something like this:

[image]

I thought about the preview and the minipage package, but I don't quite know how they could do the job.

It is important that exercise 1 and 2 might have conflicting macros, so the environments must be completely isolated and self contained. Also the exercises should be page-breakable.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Edit: Pseudocode example

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\beginex

\documentclass[preview, varwidth=500]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newenvironment{LAmatrix}{\begin{bmatrix}}{\end{bmatrix}}

...Something

\endex

...

\end{document}
```

Since this obviously doesn't work, I might use a parser to remove the documentclass and move the packages to the header and use `\begingroup ... \endgroup` to isolate the rest.

Comment: Build a framework that compiles them separately into pdfs, then include the pdfs in the final document? That won't meet the page-breakable requirement, though.

Comment: if you can add some example code it may be more clear

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222861/automatically-clean-numerous-customization-macros-gathered-in-an-auxiliary-fil

Comment: @EthanBolker I thought about something like this. I definitely wouldn't build a pdf merger myself because I'm sure there already is something like this? I couldn't find one though, that makes it look nice. As you say the page breaks are a problem with trivial implementations of pdf mergers.

Comment: @user3022127: Do you have the permission to use exercises and code from other authors at all? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proposition with `tcblisting` stuff, which is very powerful, but I restricted to the basic usage -- it can be easily extended with a lot of options.

Be sure to use the `listing only` option to the environment, otherwise `tcolorbox` tries to typeset both code and its LaTeX output. This must fail with of course with things like `\documentclass`, `\usepackage{...}`, `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.

The `2nd` argument is for specification of the task, the `3rd` argument is meant to indicate a copyright.

Better ways for this: Use`\DeclareTotalTColorBox` and related commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{texexercise}[3][]{listing only,listing options={language={TeX}}, colback=white!40!yellow, enhanced jigsaw, sharp corners, title={\TeX\ exercise \thetcbcounter\ #2\notblank{#3}{\hfill \textcopyright #3}{}},coltitle={black},colbacktitle={blue!20!white},#1}
\begin{document}

\section{Easy stuff}


\begin{texexercise}{Find the errors in this task}{By me!}
  \begin{document}
  \usepackage{foo}
  \end{document}
\end{texexercise}


\begin{texexercise}{Complete and/or correct the following code}{}
  \documentclass
  \usepackage[}{graphicx}
  \begin{document}
  \includegraphics{scale=17}[foo.gif]
  \end{document}
\end{texexercise}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the question itself is unclear: There are many possibilities to typeset questions and solutions with `tcolorbox` and its `recording` feature.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to typeset the code. They want to typeset the result of the code i.e. it is maths exercises being typeset and not LaTeX exercises. I might be wrong, though, as I find the question rather confusing.

Comment: @cfr: Well, it's confusing (or contradicting), because the screen shot tells of `macro exercises` etc.

Comment: I think it means the macros used by Exercise 1, say, and not the macros in Exercise 1. But it is not a clear question at all.

Comment: @cfr: I try to provide some a similarly unclear answer about the math stuff tomorrow (well, today, actually)